# Quick copy text in Photoshop Text layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, text, workflow

Is there a way to copy all the text within a Photoshop text layer without having to "open" the layer.

I'm hoping there's a way that I can just select the layer and then have some shortcut that copies all the contents of the text layer without having to use the Text Tool or double-clicking the layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. You have to select the text. Any other copy operation will copy pixel data, not text.

You could also double-click the thumbnail icon in the Layer Panel for the text layer. This will highlight all the text on that text layer. Then it's a simple matter of copying.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you need to enter edit mode to copy text as far as I know.

However, if your purpose of copying text is to use it in another (or in the same) photoshop file, you could always duplicate the layer.

> Shortcut to **duplicate the layer** within the same Photshop file:
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Also see [Step 1 in this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20568/12189) to quickly duplicate the layer into a new file.

Comment: I know about duplicate layer. Thank you. I ask because for web development sometimes that's the only place to get copy and when transferring from PS to code would be a lot easier to not have to open the layer each time.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will help to copy text directly from layer.

https://gist.github.com/praveenvijayan/b4c367f4b903a3f9f250

note: Only works above CS6

Copy Script into Photoshop script folder and assign a shortcut and enjoy. Saves a lot of time.

Comment: Only works above CS6

Comment: for CS3 and CS6, this script is working: http://www.bram.us/2008/03/16/ps_bramustextexport-13-automatically-export-all-text-layers-from-photoshop-psd-to-a-text-file/